# Cannot connect Windows 8 Mail to Google via EAS

Tags: google-workspace, windows-8-mail-app

I am aware that Google no longer provide EAS support for normal Gmail accounts, but my company uses a paid for Google Apps account which is still supported.

After the March 2013 updates, whenever I try to connect my Gmail account to Windows 8 Mail (Modern app), Mail tells me that this account cannot be connected using Exchange ActiveSync and gives me a link to [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/use-google-windows-8-rt).

That page specifically states that EAS is not supported *in some scenarios*. My scenario is a supported one yet I'm not allowed to connect.

Has anyone else had the same experience and solved it?

Comment: I have the same issue.  This is totally annoying.

Comment: same problem for everyone. It works fine using a windows 8 pro ultrabook so it's just a bug in the windows rt mail app version. You will have to bring the surface back for an exchange.

Comment: I'm not on a surface. I'm on Windows 8 pro on a real laptop. Have you updated the mail app to the latest version?

Comment: Just to clarify here, I'm aware that if you had an account set up before the upgrade that this account will continue to work. My issue is that I've reinstalled my laptop and can't re-add the accounts.

Comment: Just to follow on from my previous comment, my account that was set up previously is now insisting that I "upgrade" to IMAP (and lose my Calendars). Also, this is what Microsoft support have to say about the issue: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-ecoms/google-apps-integration-with-mailcontactscalendar/02f411b7-6886-492d-a568-71094348a1f3